# How to setup unit testing for multiple require module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, karma-runner, karma-coverage

I am working on a code base, where code is divided into multiple require modules.
ie each section has its own main.js with the require configuration.

I want to setup code coverage for the whole code base using Karma.

Since each section has its own requirejs config, I created a test-main.js for each module.

And have karma.config load all the test-main.js files.

I am running into issues. There is collision between baseUrl.

When testing only one module, it works fine.

Any idea ?

Comment: What happens if you chain multiple karma runners with different configurations?

Comment: That is a good suggestion. But is it possible to chain multiple karma runners ? I googled it and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple karma runners using karma programmatically.
Karma [offers an API](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/dev/public-api.html) to make it work programmatically (which is not that clear IMHO - some examples can improve it).

First of all you need an array of configurations then you need to call karma programmatically and chain the calls.

### Create an array of configurations

```
function getConfiguration(filename){
  return {
    // you can enrich the template file here if you want
    // e.g. add some preprocessor based on the configuration, etc..
    //
    // if not set in the config template 
    // make Karma server launch the runner as well
    singleRun: true,
    // point to the template
    configFile : __dirname + filename
  };
}

function createConfigurations(){
    return [getConfiguration('conf1.js'), getConfiguration('conf2.js'), etc...];
}
```

### Start Karma programmatically

```
function startKarma(conf, next){
  karma.server.start(conf, function(exitCode){
    // exit code === 0 is OK
    if (!exitCode) {
      console.log('\tTests ran successfully.\n');
      // rerun with a different configuration
      next();
    } else {
      // just exit with the error code
      next(exitCode);
  }
});
```

### Chain the karma runners

```
// Use the async library to make things cleaner
var async = require('async');
var karma = require('karma');

var confs = createConfigurations();
async.eachSeries(confs, startKarma, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log('Something went wrong in a runner');
  else {
    console.log('Yay! All the runners have finished ok');
  }
});
```

Comment: ok. I just tried running this block of code right out of (http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/dev/public-api.html) and it starts the server, but doesn't launch the browser and run the tests.

What am I missing ?

var server = require('karma').server;
            server.start({port: 9876}, function(exitCode) {
            console.log('Karma has exited with ' + exitCode);
            process.exit(exitCode);
     });

Comment: I tried your approach. It calls only the first config in the array and stops.

Comment: I've updated the code to make the runner be triggered by karma and the require. What does it print in the console before stopping?